# Waiting for Network Connection To Complete before proceeding with Func?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

I have a resume function that reestablishes a network connection before it gathers updated parameters for the app.

Issue is that it seems to be trying to get some parameters before the network link has been reestablished.

Is there a way i can pause until the connection is made?

The getParameters func is on a background thread using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void) { //code }
```

The initConnection is primary thread

Here is the func:

```
- (void)screenUnlocked {
    [self initConnection];

    CDCChannelCollectionView *scrollView;

    if ([self channelView]) {
        scrollView = [[self channelView] scrollView];
        for (CDCChannelStrip* strip in [scrollView visibleCells]) {
            [self getParameters:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:strip.channelNumber]];
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

Something like this?

```
- (void)initConnection: completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock {
    if (![self isDemo]) {
        [self setTcpControl:[[CDCControl alloc] initWithAddress:[self IPAddress] usingProtocol:TCP]];
        [[self tcpControl] setDelegate:self];
        [self setUdpControl:[[CDCControl alloc] initWithAddress:[self IPAddress] usingProtocol:UDP]];
        [[self udpControl] setDelegate:self];

        if (successful) {
            completionBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide a completion handler block to `initConnection` which is invoked when the network operation is done and update your UI in that block (don't forget to dispatch back onto the main queue)

Comment: i did try that but im having a hard time working out the syntax to do so correctly, any advice?

Comment: See http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

Comment: i updated my OP with something along these lines but im getting errors, where did i go wrong with it?

Comment: How are you calling `initConnection` and what are the errors?

Comment: im not calling it yet because its syntax is wrong and i cant work out why, errors are as follows: 'completion' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector AND Use of undeclared identifier 'successful'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148874/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jcad).

Answer (score 0):

For block syntax you can follow:

```
//Block funtion with void block return type.
- (void)initConnection:(void(^)(void))completionBlock {

    if (![self isDemo]) {
        [self setTcpControl:[[CDCControl alloc] initWithAddress:[self IPAddress] usingProtocol:TCP]];
        [[self tcpControl] setDelegate:self];
        [self setUdpControl:[[CDCControl alloc] initWithAddress:[self IPAddress] usingProtocol:UDP]];
        [[self udpControl] setDelegate:self];

        if (successful) {
            //call completion when connection is made. 
            completionBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

calling function as:

```
//Calling initConnection funtion.
    [self initConnection:^{

        NSLog(@"complition success");
    }];
```